# Skip record based on single column value without iterating through each row openxml c#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am having excel file like following structure:

```
ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF | ColG
 1   |  a   |  a   |  23  |  12  | asd  |  5
 2   |  s   |  v   |  73  |  14  | qsd  |  7
 4   |  t   |  b   |  52  |  52  | avn  |  
 2   |  y   |  t   |  13  |  71  | asx  |  2
 5   |  d   |  e   |  20  |  18  | vss  |  
 1   |  f   |  n   |  63  |  72  | ann  |  
 9   |  g   |  a   |  27  |  10  | aqz  |  15
```

I want to read and get only those rows which does not have value in `ColG`.
I can iterate every rows and match each cell value of every row using following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count(); i++)
{
    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
    int cellCounter = 0;
    foreach (Cell cell in rows.ElementAt(i))
    {
      dataRow[cellCounter] = GetCellValue(spreadSheetDocument, cell);
      cellCounter++;
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
}
```

But it is very memory and time consuming process.

Can anyone help me out to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using `DataTables` so surely there will be high memory consumption. How do you fill the tables? With SQL Adapter? I don't see you using `Cell` or `Row` from `DocumentFormat.OpenXML` so do you really want a solution with OpenXML or with SQLAdapter + DataTables?

Comment: it is just a piece of code from the whole logic.
I want it the solution using OpenXML.

Comment: Then show what you have tried using OpenXML and where you are stuck with openXML.

Comment: the above iterates for each and every row and in the above i need to add my column filter. But i want to make it happen without going row by row instead direct filtering it.

Comment: The above iterates for each and every row of the `DataTable`. You can put an `if` statement if you have a condition to check. I don't understand what is direct filtering and how can there be a filter without inspecting all elements

Comment: In short, I want it to make it happen using LINQ instead of interating using for loop.

Comment: You should probably edit your question and tags for better help. This has nothing to do with OpenXML.

Comment: Actually it has @TacyNathan , as I want help regarding fetching only those rows whose colG have no value. So how can I achieve the same using OpenXML and LINQ.